# For loop with character string

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a problem with a for loop.

I have a vector of 677 letters (and spaces, it was initially words that i splited) name "ML", I want to switch every vowel for a consonant and stock it in a vector.
But when I do my loop for l in ML, it is like if R accounts only once for every single letter he meets in ML. I can print every letter and all are switched, but as i want to stock its in a vector, R stops taking in account every "a" for example after the first one, and stops considering the "a" once he has met one.
Here is my code :

```
for (l in ML){  
if(l=="a"|l=="e"|l=="i"|l=="o"|l=="u"|l=="y") print(sample(cons,1))
else print(l)}
```

This one works but only prints every new letter without stocking its.

```
for (l in ML){`
if (l=="a"|l=="e"|l=="i"|l=="o"|l=="u"|l=="y") CS[l]= sample(cons,1, replace = TRUE)
else CS[l] = l}
```

This one doesn't work (and CS is an empty vector that I have created to fill it with the new letters.
I can not find what is wrong, except that R is only reading once every letter in my vector ML...
I can post screens of what is displayed if that can help you and if not clear...
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Instead of looping through ML directly, loop through the index, as in `for (l in 1:length(ML))` and replace `l=='a'` with `ML[l]=='a'` for each vowel. Otherwise you are not replacing the correct index in the vector.

Comment: Perfect it works, I had already tried with i in 1:677 and indexed with ML[i], but it didn't work I don't know why...
Thanks a lot !!